# Should we copy over the requests tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

The [requests tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-requests/info) would be an informative addition to [questions like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275134/python-script-for-web-scraping). Should we copy it over from Stack Overflow?

I have filled the [wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/python-requests/info) but do not know how to add the Code Language and the `requests` synonym.

I have tagged a handful of existing questions.

Comment: ([*"Stack Overflow"*, not *"StackOverflow"*](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) - *"Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters)."*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you keep the [rules about referencing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in mind and suspect we can tag at least a decent amount of questions with it (say, 20+ or so), I see no problem with adding a tag for this particular library and getting the information for the tag from SO.

Keep in mind this would likely show up as [python-requests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-requests), not just [requests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requests). I'm assuming you'll want the latter to be a synonym of the former. If the community agrees with that, I see no problem with this either.